# Flutter Bloc: Many states within a screen, how to handle?

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-bloc

Is it normal for me to give different states from different blocs/cubits within a screen?

For example: on one screen I have two textfields - email and password.

Email textfield has `EmailBloc` and there is a state to get the value of the textfield.

Password textfield has `PasswordBloc` and there is a state to get the value of the textfield.

The password textfield has a show/hide password button. The show/hide password button has a `ShowPasswordCubit` to change its state.

Thank you. I'm a bit confuse using bloc in flutter.

Comment: It's normal to have multiple BLOCs on a single screen - there's no hard rule against it. Depending on the complexity of the screen it's even preferable. But from the use case you have described, I would suggest you use a single BLOC for your state (but it's hard to tell without having seen your code).

Answer (score 1):

Learning by example is always a good way to go, [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-login-tutorial-with-flutter-bloc-ea606ef701ad) got me on my feet with BLoC as well as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THCkkQ-V1-8&t=1747s).

Essentially, your login page should house the main BLoC where you can pass in the email and pass values via the `TextEditingController` instead of having a separate BLoC for every textfield/widget.